# Compiling OpenACC Fortran code with Cray compiler

Tags: compilation, fortran, openacc, cray

My attempt to compile an OpenACC Fortan code with the Cray Fortran compiler ...

```
crayftn -o msqcomp -h omp -h acc msquared.f90
```

fails with the error message

```
ftn-1350 crayftn: WARNING in command line
  Command line option "-hacc" is being ignored because an accelerator target has not been specified.
```

So apparently I have to specify the target accelerator.  The thing is, I cannot find any documentation on how to do this anywhere, not in a Bing search and particularly not in the crayftn man pages.  Anyone know what flags to use?

BTW, I am trying to compile for an nvidia Tesla K40.  And I am stuck with the Cray compiler for now.  Even if I could use another compiler at the moment, I will eventually have to get this worked out for crayftn.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you do `module load craype-accel-nvidia35` ? http://docs.cray.com/books/S-3901-84/S-3901-84.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set the target by loading the appropriate module before compilation. You probably want this target:

module load craype-accel-nvidia35

You should then compile using the "ftn" wrapper command, rather than the "crayftn" command.

"-h omp" is the default for the Cray compiler, so you don't need this flag.

"-h acc" is the default when the module above is loaded, so is also optional.

See "man crayftn" and "man openacc" for details.

Comment: Re: the target thing, I copied and pasted too fast.  That was one of many variations I tried in trying to get this working.  I meant to copy and paste the more "standard" variation.  Sorry.  Have edited the question.  Re: crayftn, I actually did use ftn, but I thought -- sure as shootin' -- if I put that in the question, someone would say, "Hey, we can't really tell what compiler you are using!"  Re: OpenMP, I actually do need that for this code, though I understand its not relevant to the question.  Thanks.  Am going to give your suggestion a try right now.

Comment: I mean't the "-h omp" flag was optional, as OpenMP is automatically supported. I edited the answer to make this clearer.

Comment: Not out of the woods yet, but you got me past this problem.  Am accepting your answer.  Thanks.